# Can Travis use the requester's allocation to run PR builds?

Tags: travis-ci, pull-request

When an open-source project gets a lot of PRs from individual users, especially if the project has OS X builds enabled, the project's build queue can get very lengthy because it only gets to run 2 jobs at a time. Is there a way to configure PRs to run using the requesting user's 2-job allocation instead of the host project's? Or is there an alternative approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option to count PR builds toward another project, no. What can help a little is to enable auto-cancellation of builds for queued pushes on the `travis project page -> more options -> settings -> click 'Auto cancel pull request builds'`. That way at least intermediate builds for PRs after new commits are pushed get skipped.